# Kafka Internal Topic "__consumer_offsets" reassigned with wrong broker ids and now corrupted

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

**Hi All,**

Earlier, In production we had single instance of KAFKA(and Zookeeper) with broker.id=0, The server was PRD-1. Everything was fine until we converted it to cluster for resiliency.

So While converting working single instance of kafka to cluster with 2 nodes, we did following change in $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
We also did similar change in zookeeper config for server.1 and server.2 properties.

**PRD-1:**

```
port=9092
broker.id=1    #Note change in broker id here. This was a mistake.
advertised.host.name=PRD-1.KPT.COM
zookeeper.connect=PRD-1.KPT.COM:2181,PRD-2.KPT.COM:2181
```

**PRD-2:**

```
  port=9092
  broker.id=2
  advertised.host.name=PRD-2.KPT.COM
  zookeeper.connect=PRD-1.KPT.COM:2181,PRD-2.KPT.COM:2181
```

After this change we brought up the cluster and it started with broker 1 and 2. Its consuming messages from multiple producers. all good and cluster is up and running.

**But,**
None of the consumers are able to connect to newly created kafka cluster to consume the messages. When I checked the internal topic which stores all consumer offsets (Topic: __consumer_offsets) I found it was created before we converted the instance into the cluster. We found following strange details:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper PRD-1.KPT.COM:2181,PRD-2.KPT.COM:2181 --topic __consumer_offsets
Topic:__consumer_offsets    PartitionCount:50   ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 4    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Clearly, Internal topic __consumer_offsets is still configured with broker.id=0(If of PRD-1 when it was running in single machine without cluster).

Seeing above situation I tried reassignment with following command.

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper PRD-1.KPT.COM:2181,PRD-2.KPT.COM:2181 --topic __consumer_offsets
Topic:__consumer_offsets    PartitionCount:50   ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0
    Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 4    Leader: 0   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 0
```

But reassignment made situation even worse now, I have 3 replicas(0,1,2) in which 0 is dead broker which no longer exist.

Also now my topic __consumer_offsets have replication factor of 3, where as I have only 2 nodes in the cluster(broker 1 and 2).

Topic reassignment is now failing with following error message.

```
ERROR: Assigned replicas (1,2,0) don't match the list of replicas for reassignment (1,2) for partition __consumer_offsets-22
ERROR: Assigned replicas (1,2,0) don't match the list of replicas for reassignment (1,2) for partition __consumer_offsets-30
ERROR: Assigned replicas (1,2,0) don't match the list of replicas for reassignment (1,2) for partition __consumer_offsets-8
ERROR: Assigned replicas (1,2,0) don't match the list of replicas for reassignment (1,2) for partition __consumer_offsets-21
ERROR: Assigned replicas (1,2,0) don't match the list of replicas for reassignment (1,2) for partition __consumer_offsets-4
ERROR: Assigned replicas (1,2,0) don't match the list of replicas for reassignment (1,2) for partition __consumer_offsets-27
.....
..
..
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-22 failed
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-30 failed
Reassignment of partition __consumer_offsets-8 failed
```

**Can someone help, what to do so that topic __consumer_offsets recognize the cluster and update its details accordingly ?.**

Or

**I need to drop topic __consumer_offsets and bounce the kafka so that it creates it automatically ?.**

Any Pointer for help/resolution/approach to try will highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Thought to post here for anyone looking for solution for the same kind of problem. Whenever internal offset topic is corrupted(Or not as per cluster setup in --describe), You need to delete it by going to Zookeeper shell and bounce the kafka/zookeeper, by this way kafka will create that topic on next restart automatically as it's internal topic. check the topic details by kafka-topic.sh with --describe option. You should be able to see topic is getting created as per your cluster details(leader, ISR and replicas details).

Comment: Hi Mehul,
Consumer offset is an admin topic. Deleting that will cause loss of untracked messages in cluster. Is there a way to migrate topic without actually deleting ?